# GCC problem: in template

Tags: c++, gcc

i have redhat with gcc 4.1.1 i have compile as "gcc test.c" and give the following error

> Error : expected '=' ,',' , ';' , ásm' or '__ attribute__' before '<' token

the code in "test.c" is as follow

```
template <typename T> class A {
public:
    T foo;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is C++ code, not C. You need to use `g++`, i.e. `g++ test.c`. Also, to avoid confusion, you should rename your file to end with `.cpp` or `.cxx`.

Answer (score 6):

Compile with `g++` and/or rename your file to `test.cpp`.

If you compile with `gcc test.c` then your file will be assumed as a C file. There's no templates in C.

Answer (score 2):

From the [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html#Invoking-G_002b_002b), compiling a file with the `.c` extension will compile your code as though it were C, not C++.  The easiest solution is to compile your code with `g++` instead.  The `g++` command sets the default language to C++ and automatically links your code against the C++ standard library.  You can do both of those with `gcc` but you have to do it by hand.  Exactly how you do that is left as an exercise. :-)